# How do I find my past posts?

Tags: discussion, search

Where is the advanced search on this site, or where can I look up my questions?

Having asked this question I realize I might never see it again!

Comment: Click on your image at top-right corner

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on your icon in the top-right corner of the page.
2. Bellow the site banner, there will be three items: *Profile*, *Activity*, *Settings*; click on **Activity**.
3. Below the summary boxes, there will be an additional menu; click on **questions**.
4. Explore the other menus to see *a lot* of information.

In theory, you could look up *all* of your stack history from there.

Answer (score 1):

You may also find the [how do I search](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/searching) page useful. There are various search axes you can use to narrow down searches, for example searching for `user:me xna` will find all posts by you including "XNA."